# Exclude directories from file search

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am searching for all files with certain file extensions in a particular folder but I want to exclude some sub directories that should not be searched. I wrote the below code for file extensions but dont know how to exclude the folders.DirList are the folders i want to exclude from search

```
   void DirSearch(string sDir)
    {
        List<string> DirList = new List<string>();
        DirList.Add("Combustor");
        DirList.Add("INLET");

        string[] extensions = { ".c", ".h", ".isi", ".isc", ".xml", ".sheet" };

        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(
               sDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => extensions.Any(ext => ext == Path.GetExtension(s))))
        {
            UpdaterUtility.UpdateFile(file);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you go!  Just add a check to see if the excluded dir is the last part of the path.  Also, include a backslash "\" at the start of the dir name.

```
void DirSearch(string sDir)
{
    List<string> DirList = new List<string>();
    DirList.Add("\\Combustor".ToUpper());
    DirList.Add("\\INLET".ToUpper());

    string[] extensions = { ".c", ".h", ".isi", ".isc", ".xml", ".sheet", ".txt" };

    foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(sDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                     .Where(s => !DirList.Any(d => Path.GetDirectoryName(s).ToUpper().Contains(d)) && extensions.Any(ext => ext == Path.GetExtension(s))))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file);

    }
}
```

Comment: Goes into excluded directory if the excluded directory contains sub directory

Comment: Then you can change the ends with to Contains.

Answer (score 1):

This is bit naive but does the job:

```
void DirSearch(string sDir)
{
    List<string> DirList = new List<string>();
    DirList.Add("Combustor");
    DirList.Add("INLET");

    string[] extensions = { ".c", ".h", ".isi", ".isc", ".xml", ".sheet" };

    foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(
           sDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(s =>!DirList.Any(d => s.StartsWith(d, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) 
    && extensions.Any(ext => ext == Path.GetExtension(s))))
    {
        UpdaterUtility.UpdateFile(file);

    }
}
```

Why is it naive: firstly it enumerates all the files, even those in the ignored dirs, and if the number of unwanted files are much larger than wanted files, you do unnecessary processing.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly there is no built-in way to filter out specific directories. So you will have to do this search recursively:

```
void DirSearch(string sDir)
{
    List<string> DirList = new List<string>();
    DirList.Add("Combustor");
    DirList.Add("INLET");

    string[] extensions = { ".c", ".h", ".isi", ".isc", ".xml", ".sheet" };

    // enumerate only files in this directory (no sub directories)
    foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(
           sDir, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Where(s => extensions.Any(ext => ext == Path.GetExtension(s))))
    {
        UpdaterUtility.UpdateFile(file);
    }

    // now recurse the subdirectories
    foreach (string subdir in Directory.GetDirectories(
           sDir, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).
        Where(sd => sd != "." && sd != ".." && !DirList.Contains(sd)))
    {
        DirSearch(Path.Combine(sDir, subdir));
    }
}
```